# Update single attribute with non-model form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page called cashcount and on the page, I want the user to be able to type in the amount of Quarters, Dimes, Nickels, Pennies (in quantity, not value), number of each type of bill, etc into the form's text fields.

When the user clicks the button to submit the data, I would like to automatically sum up all of the fields into their monetary values and store that in my shifts.startcash field (Which is of type decimal).

What is the best way to setup this form?

Here is my pages_controller.rb

```
# Cash Count
def cashcount
  @title = "Count Cashbox"
  @shift = Shift.find(session[:shift_id])
end
```

I know that in my shift's controller, I will probably want to make a method such as def update_cashstart or something like that so that I can take the values from the textfields and summarize them, but I'm unsure of how to go about doing that.

**Updated code:**

This is what I wrote, but it doesn't seem to be updating anything:

countcash.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for :shift do |f| %>
    <div class="coins">
    Coins: <br />
    Quarters: <%= f.text_field :quarters %><br />
    Dimes: <%= f.text_field :dimes %><br />
    Nickels: <%= f.text_field :nickels %><br />
    Pennies: <%= f.text_field :pennies %><br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="bills">
    Bills: <br />
    Twenties: <%= f.text_field :twenties %><br />
    Tens: <%= f.text_field :tens %><br />
    Fives: <%= f.text_field :fives %><br />
    Ones: <%= f.text_field :ones %><br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="other">
    Please enter the dollar amount of any other money in the drawer:
    Other: <%= f.text_field :others %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Shift.rb

```
before_save :sum_coinage, :unless => :all_coins_blank?
def all_coins_blank?
    if (@quarters.nil? and @nickels.nil? and @dimes.nil? and @pennies.nil? and @twenties.nil? and @tens.nil? and @fives.nil? and @ones.nil? and @others.nil?)
        true
    else
        false
    end
end

def sum_coinage
    self.cashstart = ((@quarters * 0.25) + (@nickels * 0.05) + (@dimes * 0.10) + (@pennies * 0.01) + (@twenties * 20) + (@tens * 10) + (@fives * 5) + @ones + @others)
end
```

This is the output from the rails server:

```
Started POST "/countcash" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Aug 08 17:22:30 -0400 2011
 Processing by PagesController#countcash as HTML
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Save Shift", "shift"=>{"quarters"=>"55", "others"=>"", "tens"=>"", "fives"=>"", "dimes"=>"5", "ones"=>"", "pennies"=>"", "twenties"=>"", "nickels"=>""}, "authenticity_token"=>"IQsaKJARVrQOveEC/UTll2iFZ0OWvRmvNxGkqI6DRLE=", "utf8"=>"✓"}
```

It just doesn't seem to be pushing these updates to the actual database :|

Answer (score 1):

This is something you should do in your model. I would create a virtual attribute (a model attribute which is not actually backed by the database) for each denomination you want. Then you can sum the coin values and assign them with a before_create filter.

```
class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :quarters, :nickels, :dimes, :etc
  before_create :sum_coinage

  def sum_coinage
    self.startcash = (@quaters * 0.25) + (@nickels * 0.05) + (@dimes * 0.10)
  end
end
```

And then your view can use normal input fields for the different coins like so

```
<% form_for :shift do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :quarters %>
  <%= f.text_field :nickels %>
  etc
<% end %>
```

Comment: Does that violate the MVC pattern and the issue I see with that is that the shift will already have been created. The count cash step is a single field update

Comment: It does not violate MVC, as a matter of fact this is exactly what the model is for. My solution is hiding business logic for the data from the controller. Putting it in the controller would violate MVC.

Comment: If the summing needs to happen with every update, then change before_create to before_save. You'd also want to guard from the case where all are blank assigning zero to startcash. `before_save :sum_coinage, :unless => :all_coins_blank?` and then define `:all_coins_blank?` to return true if all the coinage variables are nil.

Comment: Ehren- Thanks for your help on this. I updated the code but it still won't push the changes to the database. I edited my code from the original post. What am I missing here?

Comment: It's probably because they're being assigned as strings from params. You'll have to call `.to_i` on all the instance variables in `sum_coinage`

Comment: Thats weird. Maybe something else is going on? Are you sure the modle you're trying to save is valid? Have you written any unit tests/specs?